# Sorting record in Adobe Air

Tags: sorting, import, air, export

Ok probably barking up the wrong tree with this one but some guidance would be nice!

Currently got an app that exports data to a text file

```
stream.open(file, FileMode.APPEND);
        stream.writeUTFBytes(data1 + data2);
        stream.close();
```

and then use the following to import that data

```
var textloader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
MyTextFile_txt.text = textloader.data;
```

Now is there anyway of sorting this information (for example put it in order of data2 records)? I know sorting from a textfile is probably a little difficult. Would there be a better way of exporting the file instead? Or when importing the file can I get it to import into a specific text box.

Dunno just throwing some ideas out.

Answer (score 0):

Although not essential you can use stream.readUTFBytes instead of URLLoader.

Regarding sorting data you can add all the loaded data into an array and then use sort() on the array.

e.g.

```
var someArray:Array = [];
for (var i:int; i < loadedData.xmlNodeName.length; i++) {
someArray.push(loadedData.xmlNodeName[i]);
}
someArray.sort();
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa4.html

Comment: Sorry just got back to trying this out :)

Comment: function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
 var loadedData:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
 

 for (var i:int; i < loadedData.xmlNodeName.length; i++) 
 {
 test.push(loadedData.xmlNodeName[i]);
 MyTextFile_txt.text = loadedData.data;
 }
someArray.sort();
}

Comment: What do you mean by xmlNodeName? (I know what xml files are.) However is this where the file path of the file comes from?

Comment: I mean the name of your xml node in your xml. <items><item></item></items>. In this example 'items' is the node name.